# How do i configure GRUB to triple boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a laptop with windows 8 pre installed. I installed on that laptop RemixOS using the guide [here](https://rndmland.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/installing-remix-os/).
And after a while i decided to install ubuntu 17.04, so I resized the windows 8 partition to create a new partition of 50G for ubuntu. After that I installed ubuntu 17.04 using a live USB but when I turn on my laptop it only shows RemixOS and Windows on the boot menu. How can i configure or fix the boot menu to also show ubuntu?

Comment: If you have everything installed in UEFI mode - as it should be - then it can as simple as selecting the Ubuntu entry in the boot order. Then most likely it will boot Ubuntu directly and that's when you can do `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i managed to get into ubuntu but now i found im in a really strange situation. When I have UEFI first on my boot settings I enter into the boot that I use for RemixOS and windows and when i have legacy first i boot into ubuntu boot from which i can only enter ubuntu. I tired to enter windows but it dindt boot.

Comment: That means you installed Ubuntu the wrong way, in legacy mode. There's no other way to multiboot in that situation than the one you already found, via UEFI settings. Had you installed it correctly you wouldn't be facing that problem now.

Comment: So in order to "fix" this situation i would need to reinstall ubuntu on UEFI mode?, How do i do that?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @Zanna I did what you suggested even thogh I think it's still not an answer. But at least I tried to explain succinctly what happened and I hope that someone who already answered finally understands it.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: Windows + RemixOS installed in UEFI mode; Ubuntu installed in Legacy/CSM mode.
This has been confirmed by toggling modes in the boot order.

**Workaround**: There's no other way to multiboot with Grub, Windows's and Remix's bootloaders in that situation than the one you already found, via UEFI settings.
**Attempts to update Grub won't change anything because `os-prober` won't be able to identify the other OSs in a different mode**.

**"Last hope..."**: You may try [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), already mentioned in other answers, which can act as an independent bootloader and, with some configuration, *might* detect OSs in both modes. Results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I would suggest is this. Boot to an Ubuntu Live CD / USB and install rEFInd into your laptop. then boot to Ubuntu and go to the EFI partition and edit the grub file in Remix OS and change the timeout / delay from 5 to 0 seconds. then you can either uninstall GRUB from Ubuntu (because you can straight boot Ubuntu from rEFInd without GRUB) or change the timeout in Ubuntu GRUB by going to etc/defaults and booting GRUb from rEFInd.

Comment: The issue has been identified yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/942079/how-do-i-configure-grub-to-triple-boot?noredirect=1#comment1496042_942079 . rEFInd may work  - the author says it's *theoretically* possible - but not in the way you think ;) And it definitely has nothing to with timeout/delay.

Comment: It works for me! rEFInd cannot boot the REMIX OS kernel though, so to boot remix OS from rEFInd, you need to boot grub which boots rEFInd, but the remix OS grub screen has a timeout, so to make it look seamless you make the timeout 0 in remix OS' grub screen..

Comment: But I uninstalled grub from Ubuntu because rEFInd CAN boot Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: But you still not getting that in this case Ubuntu has been installed in Legacy mode.

Comment: Ohh crap I just realized. In that case, the guy should use boot repair and convert his Ubuntu install into EFI